# How to filter the values from the JsonObject in Android?

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

```
> {"-Kopv2EYUt7EeisRiiCz":{"deviceName":"LYF","fileUploadDate":"07\/12\/2017 2:00:57 PM"},
"-KopvA-cTtzgzSbsKTrw":{"deviceName":"LYF","fileUploadDate":"07\/12\/2017 2:01:29 PM",}}
```

How to parse  all the  "fileUploadDates" from the JsonObject ?

```
fileUploadDate = 07\/12\/2017 2:00:57 PM
fileUploadDate = "07\/12\/2017 2:01:29 PM
```

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: I suggest two options. The first is to retrieve your json object already filtered (so you can make a request with filtering params and the server send you the json filtered) and then you can parse it in a JsonObject. The second option is to retrieve the json, parse it in a JsonObject, then implement your own methods to filter by date.

If you have problem with parsing into a JsonObject, there are a lot of solved questions in StackOverflow. This is one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GSON library

```
public void parseJson(String json){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type stringStringMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String,String>>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String,Map<String,String>> map = gson.fromJson(json, stringStringMap);

        Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            Map<String,String> innerMap = (Map<String,String>)pair.getValue();
            getInnerMapDetail(innerMap);
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }
}
    public void getInnerMapDetail(Map<String,String> innerMap)
    {   
         String fileUploadDate = innerMap.get("fileUploadDate"); // you will get here
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this for your Response to Parse**

May Help you

```
try{
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
     List<String> keyList = getAllKeys(jsonObject);
     for(String key : keyList){

          JSONObject innerObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
          String deviceName = innerObject.getString("deviceName");
          String fileUploadDate = innerObject.getString("fileUploadDate");

          System.out.println(deviceName +"--"+ fileUploadDate);
      }
}catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This method will return keys

```
private List<String> getAllKeys(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException{
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();

    Iterator<?> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
    while( iterator.hasNext() ) {
        String key = (String)iterator.next();
        keys.add(key);
    }
   return keys;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to parse json objects and store in to String,like that

```
String fileUploadDate;
JSONObject -Kopv2EYUt7EeisRiiCz = new JSONObject;
fileUploadDate= sys.getString("fileUploadDate");
```

After you change string like that

```
String newfileUploadDate = string.replace("\", "");
```

you defiantly come to output.

Comment: For sure, replace method will help. First get the jsonstring as it is and then replace will do. I agree for above